# Что является лишним в вопросах?

Tags: обсуждение, приветствия

Пока смог вычленить следующее:

- **Приветствия** всех мастей. Должно быть: вопрос — ответ.
- Ранние и не только **благодарности**, ибо достаточно дать голос ответу или принять его как самый лучший ответ.
- Истории становления на путь истинный, которые **портят конкретику**.
- Описание своего **уровня познаний**.

Что есть ещё?

Comment: А лично я с этим не согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а именно?

Comment: @stackflow ну напимер этот пункт "Описание своего уровня познаний.", понимание уровня знаний автора позволяет лучше ответить на вопрос.

Comment: А почему бы не отвечать на все вопросы более подробно?) А если профи напишет `Я профи, мне разжёвывать не надо.` Т.е в любом случае на этот вопрос\ответ предназначенный для профи наткнутся новички. Вы же не будете писать  "Вам ещё рано до этого, ответ  предназначен для профи, который читает мануалы." По самому стилю написанию вопроса, по теме вопроса можно же понять что вопрос от новичка.

Comment: @stackflow я пишу на Java/C#/Node.js преимущественно. Но могу задать вопрос, скажем по питону, в котором я вообще не разбираюсь. Я новичок или нет? Нужно мне разжёвывать или моего опыта в других языках достаточно, чтобы понять ответ? Если автор укажет свой уровень знаний, то это может очень помочь при ответе, как по мне.

Comment: @Suvitruf, написать комментарий — несомненно поможет. написать **хороший** ответ — нет. потому что ответ в первую очередь пишется не для автора вопроса, а для последующих читателей, уровень знаний которых заранее неизвестен.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну, то есть, ориентироваться на максимально, скажем так, недалёкого читателя? Если вопрос про кватернионы и повороты матриц, мне нужно расписать, что такое вектора и т.п.? Я, безусловно, утрирую, но, всё же..

Comment: @Suvitruf, я думаю, ориентироваться имеет смысл на минимально информированного читателя, делая при необходимости отсылки к дополнительной информации. а вот ориентироваться при ответе лишь на уровень знаний одного конкретного человека, задавшего вопрос, по-моему, не стоит. потому и информация об этом уровне — бесполезна для написания **хорошего** ответа.

Comment: 2. Доброе слов и кошке приятно :) ИМХО, краткое "Спасибо" не портит комментарий 3. "История становления" зачастую полезна другим участникам 4. Уровень познания позволяет автору ответа понять, насколько развернутым должен быть ответ

Answer (score 5):

Отвечу цитатой Антуана де Сент-Экзюпери:

> Совершенство достигается не тогда, когда уже ничего нельзя добавить, но когда уже ничего нельзя убрать.

Answer (score 5):

Я так понимаю, этот вопрос всплыл в контексте правок, т.е. нужно ли править сообщения с таким текстом.

Вообще, очень часто в очереди вижу от вас правки вроде [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/213859), [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/213856) или [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/213606).

И если обсуждать в этом контексте, то нет, это не лишнее, к тому же, такие правки

> Никак не делают сообщения более простым к прочтению, не упрощают его
>   поиск, точность или доступность. Изменения абсолютно излишни или явно
>   ухудшают читаемость

**UPD:** вообще, на en мете [много](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits) [подобных](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267384/removing-someone-elses-thank-you) [обсуждений](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) [было](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Позиции однозначной нет. Но есть пара нюансов. К примеру, если вы удалили приветствие и т.п; хорошо, это уменьшает количество в целом бесполезной информации. НО! Если в сообщении были другие проблемы (капс лок, код тегом не обёрнут), а вы их не поправили, то такие правки отклонять. То есть, если вы хотите улучшить сообщение, то делайте это до конца, aut Caesar, aut nihil

Comment: Изменения абсолютно **излишни** или явно ухудшают читаемость...Если излишни, то зачем принимать? Ухудшают читаемость? Вы мне объясните пожалуйста, как убирание приветствия ухудшает читаемость? Ну или давайте так, **когда задают вопросы с приветствием, вы им так же отвечайте с приветствием**, ато знаете ли, как-то не по "понятиям", задающий "Здравствуйте", а вы ему сразу по делу. Где ваша вежливость? Так же с благодарностью : "Заранее спасибо!" - "Да не за что, бро.Обращайтесь!"

Comment: Убирание приветствия "никак не делает сообщения более простым к прочтению". Если в сообщение были важные правки (добавлены теги и т.п.), то можно заодно и убрать приветствие, ок, но делать правку лишь ради убирания приветствия, считаю неправильным.

Comment: Неправельным по отношению к времени на которое вы тратите при проверке подобных правок или неправельным по отношению к репутации, которую получает участник при подобных правках ? Или неправельным с точки зрения культуры? Просто опять же - `Если в сообщение были важные правки (добавлены теги и т.п.), то можно заодно и убрать приветствие, ок` получится разделение на два лагеря. Вопросы с приветствиями и без. И в итоге, могут начаться вопросы от других участников мол "Почему это моё приветствие убрали, а вот у Васи приветствие как стояло, так и стоит.".

Comment: @stackflow на en SO, к примеру, с этим ещё строже. У меня пока нету однозначного ответа по всем пунктам. Но редактировать только ради убирания приветствия я бы не стал.

Comment: Я перестану это делать, если перестанут такое принимать - **факт**. Ну или если под вашим комментарием наберётся большое количество лайкосиков. :) Только новые аккаунты регистрировать не надо)

Comment: Ссылку на "ещё строже" добавьте, если не трудно.

Comment: Я считаю, выпиливание лишнего текста *из начала* вопроса существенная правка, так как оно увеличивает долю полезной информации, попадающей в предпросмотр вопроса в результатах поиска. Вот из конца да, несущественно.

Comment: @stackflow "неправельным"  - три раза - по отношению к грамматике русского языка

Comment: @Igor, извиняюсь за неправильность неправЕльности. :)

Comment: Вот знаете, есть такое мнение насчет русских, которые пытаются общаться с иностранцами на английском, наши попытки построения предложений часто звучат очень грубо для них, потому что мы привыкли говорить в повелительном наклонении. У меня по крайней мере такая ассоциация возникла. Считаю немного вежливости в вопросе не помешает, приятнее читать.

Answer (score 4):

> Описание своего уровня познаний.

Тут не совсем согласен, если человек пишет "я новичок в Java и у меня есть вопрос...", я не буду ему писать ответ, используя Stream Api (или напишу, но только как один из вариантов). Все-таки ответ для новичка и для опытного разработчика будет отличаться.

Даже по ценности для других пользователей, они тоже могут гуглить "как сделать Х начинающему", а получать рецепт, который им не подойдет.

Плюс все-таки, я считаю, что ответ должен быть полезен не только всем остальным, но и автору, иначе никто на SO вопросы задавать не будет (какой смысл задавать вопросы если отвечают что-то бесполезное для тебя).

> Приветствия всех мастей. Должно быть: вопрос — ответ... благодарности

Ну тут тоже спорно, все-таки все мы люди, а не роботы и общаемся на разговорном языке. Не уверен, что фраза "Добрый день, подскажите как сделать..." читается дольше и хуже чем фраза "Как сделать...". По крайне мере, править вопрос только чтобы убрать приветствие или заставлять всех писать без него я бы не стал.

Comment: С первой частью согласен, по поводу же второй. "Добрый день, подскажите как сделать..."  ок, а если "Добрый день, помогите"? Или же, "Добрый день, ПОМОГИТЕ"? Не всегда всё так однозначно =/

Comment: Да тоже не вижу большой проблемы, как и "спасибо" в конце. Мы же не читаем сообщения как роботы, такие вводные слова пропускаются автоматически за доли секунды, а "доброе слово и кошке приятно" (с). Если человек привык писать вежливо, ему может быть психологически тяжело писать сразу "как сделать..." и без "спасибо" в конце. Если все равно правите сообщение - можно удалить, но специально требовать не использовать такие слова я бы не стал.

Comment: Вежливость хорошо, но, лично у меня, этот текст вызывает смену фокуса, акцентируется внимание на этот текст, а не на сам вопрос.

Comment: Приветствия уменьшают долю полезной информации, попадающей в предпросмотр вопроса в результатах поиска.

Answer (score 0):

### Приветствия всех мастей. Должно быть: вопрос — ответ.

Фразы приветствия:

- Забирают место в **кратком** описании вопроса;
- Никак не помогают в разъяснении проблемы;
- Отвлекает от сути вопроса.

Считаю правильным удалять все такие фразы без исключения, а не только те, где имеются дополнительные ошибки.

### Истории становления на путь истинный, которые портят конкретику.

Здесь так же как и с приветствиями, фразы вроде: "Пол дня потратил, весь гугл перерыл, не знаю что уже делать..." не несут никакой пользы. Думаю что спрашивающий давит на жалость. Если я трачу время на поиск вопросов на которые знаю ответы, это не значит, что я буду выбирать кому бы ответить. Ответы даются ради улучшения сообщества, пополнения библиотеки ответов и просто продвижения репутации, а не ради: вот этот потратил пол дня, то так и быть ему отвечу, а тот пускай еще помучается.

- Забирают место в описании вопроса;
- Никак не помогают в разъяснении проблемы;
- Рассчитаны на бессмысленное чувство жалости к спрашивающему.

<sub>Субъективное мнение: Может это и не эмпатично, но я не думаю что это подходящее место для эмпатии: *вопрос - ответ ничего лишнего*.</sub>

### Ранние и не только благодарности, ибо достаточно дать голос ответу или принять его как самый лучший ответ.

Полностью согласен, stackoverflow уже имеет встроенную систему поощрений.
 "Заранее спасибо", не просто плохая фраза, а вредная и опасная, и не только потому, что она увеличивает длину сообщения, но и потому, что "Заранее спасибо" мимикрирует под вежливость и заботу, хотя на деле показывает нужду и одновременно является манипуляцией.

- Забирают место в описании вопроса;
- Никак не помогают в разъяснении проблемы;
- Манипуляция.

### Описание своего уровня познаний

Не редко встречаются фразы вроде: "Я только начал изучать Java", "Я новичок в C#". Такие фразы могут влиять на объективность и рациональность ответа. Если ответ не понятен или сложен для спрашивающего, то для этого есть комментарии, в которых можно попросить автора пояснить или дополнить ответ. Так же существуют метки из которых понятно какие средства используются.

- Забирают место в описании вопроса;
- Никак не помогают в разъяснении проблемы(Но могут влиять на ответ);
- Иногда Дублируют метки.

### Мольбы и просьбы

Я бы сюда еще отнес разные фразы вроде: "Объясните, пожалуйста ...", "Помогите ...", "Подскажите ..." и прочее. Одна из целей сообщества stackoverflow - пополнять библиотеку ответов на вопросы, и просить об этом дополнительно не имеет никакого смысла.

- Забирают место в описании вопроса;
- Никак не помогают в разъяснении проблемы.

Зачастую вижу, что за такими фразами следует конкретика:

Плохо:

> Объясните, пожалуйста, почему последний div при врапе растягивается во
>   всю ширину контейнера?

Хорошо:

> Почему последний div при врапе растягивается во всю ширину контейнера?